# @startpbox error still around

Tags: colortbl

I have the latest version of colortbl.sty (12-18-2018) and the most current version of MikTex. The following code generates the error message:
"Use of @startpbox doesn't match its definition."
I am including code that produces the error (and has no error if I don't use package colortbl).

I need colortbl for other sections of my document. Is there a way to fix this error?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l|rr|ll}
 & $x$ & $y$ & $q$ & $r$ \\\\
 \hline
 (a) & $2961$ & $987$\\\\
 (b) & $567$ & $450$\\\\
 (c) & $2388$ & $309$\\\\
 (d) & $1135$ & $39$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have no problem with this code. Do you have one compiling this very code?

Comment: From where do you get that version number? I have a fully up to date texlive 2019, and by adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` the log tells be that `colortbl` has version `2018/12/12 v1.0d` which is the same version that are on CTAN.re you sure you have a fully up to date miktex, updated in both miktex user mode and miktex admin mode?

Comment: I deleted and reinstalled MikTex today. No new updates in either user or admin mode. But you sent me in the right direction with \listfiles. I had a 2002 version of colortbl in a local directory. Thanks!